# Count categories from parent 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, web-sql

I'm trying to do a count of categories and output the result for each `parent_id = 0` in *JavaScript* or *jQuery* (if it has the appropriate functions).
I have:

```
 categories_id - parent_id
 10            -      3
 19            -      2
 17            -      1
 13            -      3
 12            -      3
 15            -      3
 4             -      1
 8             -      1
 16            -      1
 9             -      1
 6             -      1
 5             -      1
 11            -      3
 18            -      2
 7             -      1
 20            -      2
 14            -      3
 22            -      4
 1             -      0
 2             -      0
 3             -      0
 21            -      0
```

Data comes dynamically from a database.
Then if I visit a `categories_id` from my list, I require to add a counter that says `category X` has `XX categories`.
This is the script in which I require it:

```
var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
var db = openDatabase("Oscommerce", "1.0", "Oscommerce Database", dbSize);

var categories={};

var list_str = '';
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT c.categories_id, c.categories_image, c.parent_id, cd.categories_name, COUNT(p2c.categories_id) AS total FROM categories c INNER JOIN categories_description cd ON c.categories_id = cd.categories_id LEFT JOIN products_to_categories p2c ON p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id GROUP BY c.categories_id, cd.categories_name ORDER BY c.sort_order, cd.categories_name', [], function (tx, results) {
list_str += '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-count-theme="a" data-split-theme="a">';
var len = results.rows.length, i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
var r = results.rows.item(i);
categories[r.categories_id] = r;
//console.log(categories);
console.log(r.categories_id+'-'+r.parent_id);
}

for(key in categories)
{

var parent = 0;  
var value=categories[key];
catId = value['categories_id'];
catName = value['categories_name'];
catImage = value['categories_image'];
parentId = value['parent_id'];
total = value['total'];

if (parentId == parent) 
{  

if (total == 0){    
list_str += '<li id="'+ catId +'"><a class="parentlink" parentid="'+ parentId +'" catid="'+ catId +'" catname="'+ catName +'"><h3>' + catName + '</h3><p>' + catImage + '</p><div class="ui-li-count">'+ total +' products</div></a><a class="parentlink" parentid="'+ parentId +'" catid="'+ catId +'" catname="'+ catName +'">somelink</a></li>';
}else{
list_str += '<li id="'+ catId +'"><a class="parentlink" parentid="'+ parentId +'" catid="'+ catId +'" catname="'+ catName +'"><h3>' + catName + '</h3><p>' + catImage + '</p><div class="ui-li-count">'+ total +' products</div></a><a href="#">somelink</a></li>';
}

}
}

list_str += '</ul>';

$('#parents').html(list_str).find('ul').listview();


}); 
});
```

Comment: Wait, what? Where does jQuery/JavaScript play into this question?

Comment: Are you looking for a javascript function to do this or an SQL query?

Comment: If you can control the query that the database issues, it would be much better to build the histogram in SQL.

Comment: @MarceloCantos somehow i cant figure out how to do an aditional db query with webDB in javascript and pass the output to the next db query in the same function/pageload (i'm not a professional coder,above code took me since may)

Comment: The "Web SQL Database" specification is deprecated and no longer maintained (browsers actually drop support for it), you should try to use IndexedDB instead, look here is a great tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/